# Get all the values of a dataGridTextboxColumn

Tags: c#, monthcalendar, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have a dataGridView that has a column called Date Due which is of type System.DataTime. I want to put these dates in a monthCalendar. Do I have to iterate throught the column? Do I have to cast it?

Comment: Is this web or forms app? I think it is forms (datagridviewtextboxcell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get date from each column YES you have to iterate through all rows in column. As you are displaying date as text you will need to parse using `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse` methods.

EDIT:- supposing this is a forms application. I added a `DataGridView`, a `MonthCalendar` and a `Button`. I was able to get dates from gridview and bold the selected dates in month cal.

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CreateData();
}

private void CreateData()
{
    var dtb = new DataTable();
    dtb.Columns.Add("Column1");
    dtb.Columns.Add("Column2");
    dtb.Columns.Add("Column3");

    var dt = DateTime.Now;
    var rand = new Random();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var r = dtb.NewRow();

        r.ItemArray = new object[] {dt.ToString("ddd"), dt.ToString("MMM"), dt};
        dt = dt.AddDays(rand.Next(30));

        dtb.Rows.Add(r);
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtb;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bds = new List<DateTime>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        var b = DateTime.TryParse(row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 1].Value+"", out dt);
        if(!b) continue;

        bds.Add(dt);
    }

    cal.BoldedDates = bds.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I already have a DataSet as the DataGrid's DataSource. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I will also be using the `MonthCalendar.UpdateBoldedDates()` method when a new row is added. There is no need for a button.

Comment: Then you ignore the creation of `DataTable` and binding stuff. When new row is added you can handle that event and get data from the corresponding column.

Comment: Or better still post some code so that I have an Idea what and how your stuff is now.